# Including and excluding specific records

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I want to find some of buyer who had special condition (in this case, transaction >= 600000 called star member)

In this case, I want to find out star member (transaction >= 600000) who exists in January 2020 and March 2020, but it does not include star member who is doing transaction in February 2020.

here's my syntax

```
SELECT users_id 
FROM order_star_member  
GROUP BY users_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'January' 
                THEN total_price_star_member END) >= 600000
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'March' 
                THEN total_price_star_member END) >= 600000
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_star_member
    GROUP BY users_id
    having sum(case when monthname(createdAt) = 'February'
    THEN total_price_star_member END) >= 600000);
```

and here's my fiddle

```
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c85037215fe71f700b51c8fd3a5ae76
```

on my fiddle, the expected result are the users_Id 15 because that id order at january and march but not in february

Comment: what is "doing transaction in February 2020" mean? Which users_id do you expect to return in your fiddle?

Comment: so based on my fiddle, it should be users_id '15' who doing transaction in january and march but not in february @danblack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in the inner `t` we group by month to determine all the star members.

The outer grouping groups by user_id. Their score is the sum of their star_member.

For February (m=2 (February being the second month) on the first line of the query below) if they are a star_member, they get an penalty (-100) as an arbitrary value that the `SUM` cannot overcome.

The only way a `month_score=2` can exist if if a user has a star_member being true (1) for both January and March but not February.

```
SELECT users_id, SUM(IF(m=2 and star_member, -100, star_member)) as month_score
FROM
  (SELECT users_id,
          MONTH(createdAt) as m,
          SUM(total_price_star_member) >= 600000 as star_member
  FROM order_star_member  
  WHERE createdAt BETWEEN '20190101' AND '20190331'
  GROUP BY users_id, m
) t
GROUP BY users_id
HAVING month_score=2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37d242dabc7f8c8d7dafe0ea5b9196a3)

Comment: thankyouuu, i will try your query, but can you explain me which part i should change if i want to something like different criteria like star member on january and february but not on march, or february and march but not in january

Comment: m is the  1-12 month number. So for March it would be m=3 in the outer group by. m=1 for January.

Comment: sorry, so if i want to find out users where exists on january and february but not on march, which syntax i should change?

Comment: so for "not march", same as above replacing the outer group by line with `GROUP BY users_id, IF(m=3, NOT star_member, star_member)`.  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=969c74b206209306ef8a4284b62180cc) last two queries

Comment: how about for not march and february, so there's exists just in january, can you explain it? @danblack

Comment: I changed the answer a bit, there was a flaw. Hopefully the explanation added sufficient. Hopefully you can apply your new criteria to the scoring on line.

Comment: hey sir, i just tryna your last syntax, i tried used where the data exists in march and january, it should be 2 users_id (14 and 15) but why only 14

Comment: Is see both 14 and 15